# Updating GEF Model from a background thread

Tags: multithreading, eclipse, eclipse-gef

i'm trying to update a Model for GEF and have the changes shown in the view i've created.  Currently no change I make is being reflected in the view, i'm using the following approach to update the model and am wondering if its the right approach to take:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
            String viewId = "beat.views.BeatView";

            IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();

            IWorkbenchWindow mainWindow = workbench
                    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

            try {

                BeatView view = (BeatView) mainWindow.getActivePage()
                        .showView(viewId);

                BeatEditPart beatEditPart = (BeatEditPart)view.getGraphicalViewer().getContents();

                BeatModel beatModel = (BeatModel)beatEditPart.getModel();
                beatModel.setObjects(model);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your EditPart listening to model changes?

1 - You need to register as a listener to your model. We use EMF's notify mechanism.

```
public void activate() {
    if (!isActive())
        ((EObject) getModel()).eAdapters().add(this);
    super.activate();
}

public void deactivate() {
    if (isActive())
        ((EObject) getModel()).eAdapters().remove(this);
    super.deactivate();
}
```

2 - You need to act when something changes.

```
public void notifyChanged(Notification notification) {
...
}
```